# Azure Virtual Network Custom DNS

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, azure, subnet

I created a virtual network and put 2 VMs in one subnet. But they were not able to ping each other using their hostnames. I need a DNS Server implemented so that hostnames in the subnet can be resolved to IP addresses. How do I do that? Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum it up:

1. Install and configure DNS on one of the Vnet servers: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730921.aspx
2. Assign an internal static IP to the VM you installed DNS on: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-private-ip/
3. Configure the Vnet to use the DNS IP addresses for name resolution:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-manage-dns-in-vnet/
4. Restart your VMs at least once to get the new configuration.

Comment: After this will I be able to ping machines like `ping machine01` using just the hostnames?

Comment: Assuming that you do everything correctly, then the answer is yes!